# Is it possible to remove an index with org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ReactiveElasticsearchTemplate?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

The non-reactive counterpart of Elasticsearch Spring Data's `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate` provides a method `public boolean deleteIndex(String indexName)`, which I can use to delete indices. However, I cannot find any hints of similar functionality in the `ReactiveElasticsearchTemplate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DefaultReactiveElasticsearchClient` which is created by

```
ReactiveRestClients.create(ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration)
```

implements the interface `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.ReactiveElasticsearchClient.Indices` which has two methods to delete an index:

```
    default Mono<Void> deleteIndex(DeleteIndexRequest deleteIndexRequest) {
        return deleteIndex(HttpHeaders.EMPTY, deleteIndexRequest);
    }

    default Mono<Void> deleteIndex(Consumer<DeleteIndexRequest> consumer) {
        DeleteIndexRequest request = new DeleteIndexRequest();
        consumer.accept(request);
        return deleteIndex(request);
    }

    default Mono<Void> deleteIndex(DeleteIndexRequest deleteIndexRequest) {
        return deleteIndex(HttpHeaders.EMPTY, deleteIndexRequest);
    }
```

So nothing to pass in an index name directly, but `DeleteIndexRequest`has a constructor that just takes index name(s).

```
((DefaultReactiveElasticsearchClient)client).deleteIndex(new DeleteIndexRequest(indexname)).
```

So currently it's ugly with this cast but can be done. We have [a ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-678)  to add this functionality in the `Operations` interface and implementations.